# Handling Exception thrown by a Callable from a Thread Pool

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a spring `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` I `submit` some `Callable` tasks to this `Executor`.

Inside the `Task` I use a dynamic `Map` to set some values. And the `Future` of this `Callable` could be used to cancel this thread. Before starting this `Callable` I initialize some conditions, which are nullified or reverted back when the thread completes execution.

There might be a case when the `Task` has not started and it is cancelled. This means that the conditions have been initialized. But when a Thread that has not been started and is still with the pool, is cancelled I am unable to nullify my initializations as the `call` method is never called.

I read about it and if it was a `Runnable` thread then I could have handled it using the `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. Or if I was using `future.get()` to wait for the result then I could have handled the `ExecutionException`. Another solution is to override the `afterExecute()` but I could not find this in `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, also I am not very sure about this approach.

SO how do I handle it in this case?

The below code is called from a demon thread waiting on a `BlockingQueue`:

```
public void process(View view)
{
    //getMapOfViewsAndFuture and getMapOfViewsPersistingLocks fetch the ConcurrentHashMaps
    viewController.getMapOfViewsAndFuture().remove(view.getId());
    viewController.getMapOfViewsPersistingLocks().put(view.getId(), new ReentrantLock());
    Callable<WebResponse> calculatePI = (Callable<WebResponse>) mAppContext.getBean("piCalculator", view.getId()
        ,viewController.getMapOfViewsPersistingLocks().get(view.getId()), viewController.getMapOfViewsPrintingLocks().get(view.getId()));
    Future<WebResponse> future = mExecutor.submit(calculatePI);
    viewController.getMapOfViewsAndFuture().put(view.getId(), future);
}
```

The Callable (PICalculator) looks like this:

```
class PICalculator implements Callable<WebResponse>
{   
    @Override
    public WebResponse call()
    {
        try
        {
            //business logic
            mWebResponse = getResponse();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //log the exceprtion
        }
        finally
        {
            //remove this entry from datasets
            viewController.getMapOfViewsAndFuture().remove(mViewId);
            viewController.getListOfCalculatingViews().remove((Integer)mViewId);
            viewController.getMapOfViewsPersistingLocks().remove(mViewId);
        }

        return mWebResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: enclose entire call() method code block in try{}catch{}finallly{} block. In your code, even finaly{} block required try{}catch{}

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, With the Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, you can provide configuration for `ThreadPoolExecutor`(Java's inbuilt) like - `corePoolSize, maxPoolSize` etc., but you cannot set your custom ThreadPoolExecutor.

In this case, I will suggest you to use Spring's **ConcurrentTaskExecutor**,

1. Create an object of Java's ThreadPoolExecutor with the required configuration. See below constructor:

   ```
    public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                             int maximumPoolSize,
                             long keepAliveTime,
                             TimeUnit unit,
                             BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)
   ```

Here you have to provide your own queue object.

2. Now you can override the afterExecute() method for cleanup the settings, as below:

   ```
       ThreadPoolExecutor myExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3,5,5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10)){

               protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
                   super.afterExecute(r,t);
                   //Move your cleanup code here
                   //remove this entry from datasets
                  viewController.getMapOfViewsAndFuture().remove(mViewId);
             viewController.getListOfCalculatingViews().remove((Integer)mViewId);
                  viewController.getMapOfViewsPersistingLocks().remove(mViewId);
                   System.out.println("do cleanup here");
              }
       };
   ```
3. Now set this executor in ConcurrentTaskExecutor object.

   ```
   ConcurrentTaskExecutor.setConcurrentExecutor(myExecutor);
   ```

   You can even pass your executor in the constructor of ConcurrentTaskExecutor.

   ```
     ConcurrentTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(myExecutor);
   ```

Now your `taskExecutor` is ready to process your tasks,  just call `submit(callable)` method to pass callables/runnables(tasks).  Hope It may help you.